# Regex for nested pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a pattern like this:

```
#alphanumericX(anythingY){
    anythingZ
}#
```

It can be nested like this:

```
#alphanumeric1(anything1){
    #alphanumericX(anythingY){
        anythingZ
    }#
}#
```

Or like this:

```
#alphanumeric1(anything1){
    anything2
    #alphanumericX(anythingY){
        anythingZ
    }#
}#
```

The patterns can be written not just once, but multiple like this:

```
#alphanumericX(anythingY){
    anythingZ
}#
#alphanumeric1(anything1){
    anything1
}#
```

I want a regex to match the the patterns above, so it will return like this:

```
#alphanumericX(anythingY){
    anythingZ
}#
```

How to achieve that?

Here is my current regex: `/#(.*?)\((.*?)\)\{(.*?)\}#/sm`

Comment: Can you please show actual data here instead of just samples?

Comment: use capture groups with `preg_match_all()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important token to know about when matching recursive inputs is `(?R)` (which recurses the entire pattern), or `(?1)`, where the digit after the `?` indicates the subpattern to recurse.

Here, you can use

```
#\w+\(\w+\){(?:(?R)|.)*?}#
```

https://regex101.com/r/iMUAZM/1

- `#\w+\(\w+\)` - Match `#`, word characters, `(`, word characters, and `)`
- `{` - Match opening bracket
- `(?:(?R)|.)*?` Repeatedly match either

  - `(?R)` This whole pattern again, or
  - `.` - Any character, until
- `}#` - End of the pattern